# Stopping an electro magnet clutch from sticking

Tags: door, motors

[image]

I have a Dorman 747-300 Sliding Door Motor for a Dodge Grand Caravan.

The motor has a magnetic disc that will engage a brass "Clutch" with motor to open/close the door automatically. When the door is manually operated the clutch is to be disengaged from the motor and allow the door to move freely and not "fight" against the motors gears.

The problem is that the clutch is stuck to the motor gear and therefore makes it difficult to operate the door manually.

I have disassembled the part and cleaned the mating surfaces and relieving any suction/attraction that the parts have together. This allows for "free" manual operation, but it does not last long. After the door is used with the automatic button and the motor is used it gets "stuck again. Any way to remedy this sticking?

[image: Inside Motor]

Comment: I do not have the ability to send a reverse polarity pulse to the motor. This is a motor for a Dodge Grand Caravan 2004 sliding side door..

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Has it always been this way? Or only when it got older? Maybe the spring has weakened.

Comment: There is no spring in the system that I can see.

Aside: Is there a way for me to add another image to the question?

Comment: The spring might be inside the solenoid itself. Something has to counter the motion produced by the magnetic field when it is turned off.

Comment: I will have to tack it apart and check for a spring action. The way it honestly looks is if to have the magnet push the brass clutch into the black plastic cog with the teeth that seat into the brass clutch the magnet would actually be "pushed" away from the solenoid. And possibly a solenoid magnetic attraction to pull it from the motor. Either the magnet is not being pulled away from the motor or the brass clutch is staying "stuck" to the black plastic motor cog through some kind of means.

Comment: Logically would't be in opposite what your claim? The clutch is engaged when the motor spins, and it is disengaged while the motor has no power, so you can freely move it by hands?

Comment: Marko, I may not have been clear and I have edited the original post. You are correct that the clutch must disengage for free operation, but for some reason it is staying engaged.

Comment: As suggested earlier, there should be a purely mechanical action that moves the clutch in the neutral position, almost certainly the spring is involved.

Comment: I will remove both the Right and Left Side Motors and inspect for a spring, but I have never seen one.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I can't answer the question for you, the question appears to be a great fit for the site ... again ... Welcome!

Comment: I have removed the driver's side sliding door motor while having the door open to replace a failed Sliding Door Lock Actuator.
I shot a video to better explain the "Sticking" in the Clutch mechanism that is happening.
We will see if video links can be placed in this forum.
[Sliding door motor NOT disengaging][1]


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2DayUpG15A

Comment: I place some packing tape between the silver side of the magnet and the "brass" clutch piece. The shaft rotated freely.. Once installed the tape does not stop the magnetic engagement of the clutch and shaft, but also when the magnetic field is interrupted the door now move "freely" in manual position.